# SVG linearGradient animation with loop

Tags: animation, svg

Thanks to this topic (pretty old, that's why I'm opening a new one) [Animating SVG path fill bottom-top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38344737/animating-svg-path-fill-bottom-top)

I finally succeed to do a SVG animation from bottom to the top as I want to :

```
<linearGradient id="fill" x1="0.5" y1="1" x2="0.5" y2="0">
     <stop offset="0%" stop-opacity="0" stop-color="#76b442">
          <animate attributeName="offset" values="0;1" repeatCount="1" dur="1s" begin="0" fill="freeze"></animate>
          <animate attributeName="stop-opacity" values="0;1" repeatCount="1" dur="0.1s" begin="0" fill="freeze"></animate>
     </stop>
     <stop offset="100%" stop-opacity="0" stop-color="#76b442">
          <animate attributeName="offset" values="0;1" repeatCount="1" dur="1s" begin="0" fill="freeze"></animate>
          <animate attributeName="stop-opacity" values="0;1" repeatCount="1" dur="1s" begin="3s" fill="freeze"></animate>
     </stop>
</linearGradient>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8v5f3cgk/

The only problem is that I want to make it looping from top to bottom. And in an undefinite way, how could I reach this ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: what's an "undefinite way" mean?

Comment: I mean like the animation never stop. I explain myself : it's a preloader of a HTML page, so I want the animation to loop until the page is fully load